# Unable To Set Date in DatePicker Swift

Tags: swift

I have a common datePicker, 
where in Part 1 of the code (which is executed when datePicker is changed) I am setting  datePicker's  minimumDate and maximumDate and this works.

In Part 2 of the code (which is executed when cell is tapped) I am only setting the datePickers date.

**When Part 1 is followed by Part 2 of the code I am unable to set datePickers date i.e the datePicker shows the maximumDate set (which is done in part 1 of the code)**

When Part 2 of the code executed without part 1, I am able to set the datePickers date.

Can someone please advice where I could be going wrong ?

**Part 1**

```
let endTimeString           =   self.timesArray[row]["endTime"]!
let endTimeObject           =   self.convertToDateObject(timeString: endTimeString)
let maxStartTimeObject      =   endTimeObject.addingTimeInterval(-5 * 60.0)            // removing 5mins
cell.datePicker.maximumDate =   maxStartTimeObject


let startTimeString = self.timesArray[row]["startTime"]
let startTimeObject       =   self.convertToDateObject(timeString: startTimeString!)
let minEndTimeObject    =   startTimeObject.addingTimeInterval(5 * 60.0)            // adding 5mins
cell.datePicker.minimumDate = minEndTimeObject
```

**Part 2**

```
cell.datePicker.date = dateObject
```

Comment: Is it possible that the date you are trying to set it outside your min/max bounds?

Comment: You are correct !! when I am trying to just set time (e.g 9:00 am) in my datePicker using a String (e.g "9:00 am") I notice that the year was also being set automatically, how can I avoid this ? as this seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: @Thomas,  Post your comment as an answer and I shall accept it.

Comment: Sure thing! Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that the date you are trying to set it outside your min/max bounds?